# Use an event handler provided by a library

Tags: c#, events

I've been trying to figure out how to use this event handler from the library ImageListView. I've been trying for the last half hour and I'm completely lost and have no clue how to use this thing. I haven't been able to type anything that comes close to compiling. Here's what I am trying to use [image: what i'm trying to use]

and here is the documentation on it
https://oozcitak.github.io/imagelistview/obj/api/Manina.Windows.Forms.ImageListView.html#Manina_Windows_Forms_ImageListView_ItemClick

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem (and looking at the source), it should be as simple as

```
seriesCoverList.ItemClick += DoItemClick;

...

public void DoItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Note just to clarify, `ItemDoubleClick` has the same signature

```
seriesCoverList.ItemDoubleClick += DoItemDoubleClick;

...

public void DoItemDoubleClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Note from [xWolfz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10252192/xwolfz)

> You also need
>
> ```
> using Manina.Windows.Forms;
> ```

Comment: It is unclear if the OP talks about ItemClick or ItemDoubleClick, but OK.

Comment: I was talking about ItemDoubleClick, it was the one I had hovered over in the screenshot, but I probably should have specified that somewhere. I was able to modify the code above to work for double click. In case anybody else ever find this thread in the future, I would like to add that you need `using Manina.Windows.Forms;`